Filtering a recursive group to show all ancestors and descendants of matched items
I'm using SSRS/Paginated Reports to build out a tree of Jira issues, using the issue's ParentID as the recursive parent on the group. It works fine and I can filter on team, assignee etc.
Our issuetype hierarchy is 'Initiative' is parent of 'Epic' is parent of 'Story' is parent of 'Task'. Issues may be orphans without parents, and hierarchy levels may be skipped (that is, a 'task' may have an 'initiative' as a parent with no 'Epic' or 'story' in between)
Some issues are tagged [foo] and I want to apply a filter to show all issues with that tag and ALL ancestors and descendants of those tagged issues, even if the ancestor/descendant issues are not tagged. I can ignore tagged issues that are not issuetype 'Epic' (unless they are a descendant of an tagged Epic)
I'm not really sure  how to approach this. Can I do it in Report Builder/RDL? Or should I be doing something with DAX to filter the dataset?
I have extracted all tagged issues and all issues with issuetype 'Initiative' into a dataset and I can match the tagged 'Epics' with untagged parent 'Initiatives' using LOOKUPSET to filter out untagged Initiatives without descendants, but that only works for checking one level up
Any suggestions will be gratefully considered.
thnaks!

I think you may be wanting/needing Understanding functions for parent-child hierarchies in DAX - in particular PATHCONTAINS at the bottom.
